# Is it possible to vacuum distill citric acid?

Tags: distillation

I'm wondering if

1. it is at all possible to vacuum distill citric acid without the slightest decomposition;
2. it is something that can easily be done in a small lab with widely available equipment.

I've looked on internet and found the following data:

- ~154 °C melting point (anhydrous citric acid)
- ~175 °C starts decomposing
- ~310 °C boiling point
- ~$10^{-8}$ mmHg vapor pressure at 25 °C

Comment: If you have enough to do a real distillation (not say Kugelrohr), you should have enough for a recrystallization, and I suspect you'll get better results.

Comment: @Zhe This is true, but they have different effects and thus could be complementary. Do you know if such a distillation is possible and easy to set up in a small lab?

Comment: Itaconic acid is formed by the distillation of citric acid. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itaconic_acid

Comment: @User55119 That's interesting. I had never heard of itaconic acid before. The wikipedia page does not explain how dry distillation of citric acid turns it into this other substance. Is it the thermal degradation product of citric acid?

Comment: Given that the citric acid has an appreciable vapor pressure at 25 °C, I'd look into purification using vacuum sublimation.

Comment: @MaxW Good point, but I don't trust that number. 10mmHg vapour pressure should give a well notiveabele acidic smell, which citric acid doesn't have.

Comment: The thermal conversion of citric acid is a decarboxylative dehydration to form the double bond of itaconic acid.

Comment: @MaxW & Karl:I don't know how to format the vapor pressure properly for clear reading but it should read as ten to the minus 8th power. It's a fairly low vapor pressure

Comment: @User 55119: Thanks for that information! Would you know at which temperature this decarboxylative dehydration starts taking place (i.e. the temperature under which it will not occur at all)?

Comment: @Hans 10^–8 mmHg  written as \$\pu{e-8 mm Hg}\$  is shown as $\pu{e-8 mm Hg}$ ( inline mode)

Comment: Or 10^-8 can be written as \$10^{-8}\$ seen as  $10^{-8}$. See [MathJax](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) for eventual formatting of formulas or expressions.

Comment: Here is the Org. Syn. prep: http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV2P0368 The itaconic anhydride is distill at 175-190oC but the citric acid is heated in the pot with an open flame. Hydrolysis of the anhydride affords the diacid.

Comment: @Poutnik: I updated the text with the appropriate format. Thank you!

Comment: @User55119: Useful information. The distilling temp seems to correspond to the temperature at which citric acid starts to decompose so maybe itaconic acid is a / the main degradation product.